# Authentication tips using NTAG 424 DNA TT

Tags: authentication, encryption, aes, nfc, cmac

I need to implement an authentication procedure between a reader an NFC tag but being my knowledge limited in this area I will appreciated **some aid in order to understand few concepts.**

**Pardon in advance for rewrite the Bible but I could not summarize it more.**

There are many tags families ( ICODE, MIFARE, NTAG...) but after doing a research I think NTAG 424 DNA matches my requirements(I need mainly authentication features).

It comes with AES encryption, CMAC protocol and 3-pass-authentication system and here is when I started to need assistance.

**AES** -> As I am concerned this is a block cipher to encrypt plain texts via permutations and mapping. Is a symmetric standard and it does not use the master key, instead session keys are used being them derivations from the master key. **(Q01: What I do not know is where this keys are stored in the tag. Keys must be stored on specialized HW but no tag "specs" remark this, apart from MIFARE SAM labels.)**

**CMAC** -> It is an alteration of CBC-MAC to make authentication secure for dynamically sized messages. If data is not confidential then MAC can be used on plain-texts to verify them, but to gain confidentiality and authentication features "Encrypt-than-mac" must be pursuit. Here also session keys are used, but not the same keys used in the encryption step.**(Q02: The overall view of CMAC may be a protocol to implement verification along with confidentiality, this is my opinion and could be wrong.)**

**3-pass-protocol** -> ISO/IEC 9798-2 norm where tag and reader are mutually verified. It may also use MAC along with session keys to achieve this task.**(Q03: I think this is the upper layer of all the system to verify tags and readers. The "3 pass protocol" relays in MAC to be functional and, if confidentiality features are also needed, then CMAC might be used instead of single MAC. CMAC needs AES to be functional, applying session keys on each step. Please correct me if I am posting savages mistakes)**

/*********/

P.S: I am aware that this is a coding related forum but surely I can find here someone with more knowledge than me about cryptography to answer this questions.

P.S.S: I totally do not know where master and session keys are kept in the Tag side. Have they need to be include by a separate HW along with the main NFC circuit ?

(Target)

This is to implement a mutual verification process between tag and reader, using the NTAG 424 DNA TagTamper label. (The target is to avoid 3º parties copies, being authentication the predominant part instead of message confidentiality)

Lack of knowledge of cryptography and trying to understand how AES, CMAC and the mutual authentication are used on this NTAG.

(Extra Info)

**NTAG 424 DNA TT:** https://www.nxp.com/products/identification-security/rfid/nfc-hf/ntag/ntag-for-tags-labels/ntag-424-dna-424-dna-tagtamper-advanced-security-and-privacy-for-trusted-iot-applications:NTAG424DNA

**ISO 9798-2:** http://bcc.portal.gov.bd/sites/default/files/files/bcc.portal.gov.bd/page/adeaf3e5_cc55_4222_8767_f26bcaec3f70/ISO_IEC_9798-2.pdf

**3-pass-authentication:**https://prezi.com/p/rk6rhd03jjo5/3-pass-mutual-authentication/

**Keys storage HW**:https://www.microchip.com/design-centers/security-ics/cryptoauthentication

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Comment: Summarizing, where master and session keys are kept in the Tag side, and if any kind of MAC is applied on the 3-pass-authentication protocol.

Comment: Did you solved this? I also want to use the tags but the verification of the CMAC is not easy understandable.

Answer (score 6):

The NTAG424 chips are not particularly easy to use, but they offer some nice features which can be used for different security applications. However one important thing to note, is that although it heavily relies on encryption, from an implementation side, that is not the main challenge, because all of the aes encryption, cmac computation and so on is already available as some sort of package or library in most programming languages. Some examples are even given by nxp in their [application note](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN12196.pdf). For example in python you will be able to use the `AES` package `from Crypto.Cipher import AES` as stated in [one of the examples of the application note](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN12196.pdf#page=12).

My advice is to simply retrace their [personalization example](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN12196.pdf#page=24) beginning at the initial authentication, and then work your way up to whatever you are trying to achieve. It is also possible to use these examples in order to test the encryption and the building of apdu commands. Most of the work is not hard, but sometimes the NXP documents can be a bit confusing.

One small note, if you are working with python, there is some code available on [github](https://github.com/topics/ntag424) which you might be able to reuse.

Answer (score 4):

For iOS, I'm working on a library for DNA communication, NfcDnaKit:

https://github.com/johnnyb/nfc-dna-kit